# Getting error while running "node compile.js" for local deployment

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error while running **node compile.js**

The error is as follow;

```sh
C:\Users\PC\HealthcareDPL\compile.js:30
].HealthcareDPL;
 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'HealthcareDPL')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\HealthcareDPL\compile.js:30:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\HealthcareDPL\deploy.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Kindly help me with this issue.

My code for compile.js file is below:

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

const healthcarepath = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  "contracts",
  "healthcaredpl.sol"
);
const source = fs.readFileSync(healthcarepath, "utf8");

const input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    "healthcaredpl.sol": {
      content: source,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

module.exports = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts[
  ":healthcaredpl.sol"
].HealthcareDPL;

console.log(JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts);
```

Comment: Can you post your compile.js

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question. You can see it there.

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'HealthcareDPL') at Object.` is the clue.

I'm unsure of the structure of the parsed `solc.compile...` etc... but it looks like you are trying to access the array `contracts` by passing a string value `[ ":healthcaredpl.sol" ]`, which cannot happen in javascript.

I would remove the `HealthcareDPL`, and `console.log(module.exports)` to ascertain how this value is actually accessible.

Comment: XaEk I got this issue after updating npm modules to the latest version @9.2.0. Before this update, all the files were running properly.

Comment: have you updated your dependencies in your `package.json` ?

Comment: Yes, all of the dependencies which are present in the package.json file are updated according to the latest version. Please let me know that node modules are not present in package.json file, should I add it in it for the latest version?